# Eigenvalues of a Matrix over the Complex Numbers

Tags: analysis

I am looking at this question at the moment: If M is a N×N matrix over ℂ,  with $M_{nm}$:=$\frac{N+1}{2}$ if n=m, and $M_{nm}:=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{2\pi(m-n)}{N}}-1}$ if   n≠m, then show that the eigenvalues of the matrix are {1,...,N}. I was able to show that 1 will always be an eigenvalue because (1,...,1) is  an eigenvector for 1. But I am not sure how to prove the the other ones. At the moment I am trying to do it by determining eigenvectors, is that the correct approach? I would assume one could also do it over the characteristic polynom but I think calculating that would be rather tricky. I would greatly appreciate any ideas or hints!

Answer (score 0):

Let's write out some of these for low $N$ to try to build intuition.

$N=3:$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}&\frac{1}{\gamma_3^2-1}\\
\frac{1}{\gamma_3^{-1}-1}&2&\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}\\
\frac{1}{\gamma_3^{-2}-1}&\frac{1}{\gamma_3^{-1}-1}&2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}&\frac{1}{\gamma_3^2-1}\\
\frac{\gamma_3}{1-\gamma_3}&2&\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}\\
\frac{\gamma_3^2}{1-\gamma_3^2}&\frac{\gamma_3}{1-\gamma_3}&2
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
2&\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}&\frac{1}{\gamma_3^2-1}\\
-1-\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1} &2&\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}\\
-1-\frac{1}{\gamma_3^2-1}&-1-\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Where $\gamma_n=e^{2\pi/N}$.  Also, note that $\frac{\gamma_3}{1-\gamma_3}=\frac{(\gamma_3-1)+1}{1-\gamma_3}=-1-\frac{1}{\gamma_3-1}$.  Note that this has each diagonal equal to some constant number.  Note only that, but notice the symmetry of the diagonals above and below the diagonal.  If we say that $D_i$ is the value on the diagonal, and $D_0$ is the value on the main diagonal, $D_1$ is the value one above that, and $D_{-1}$ is one below that, we have that $D_{-i}=-1-D_i$ (for $i\neq 0$)

Note that these symmetries hold for higher $n$.  This symmetry (where each diagonal is some constant) is known as a [Toeplitz Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).  It may be helpful for you to look into them.  Note that toeplitz matrices don't in general have the $D_{-i}=-1-D_i$ symmetry, so this may end up being very useful for you.

It also might be useful to notice that you matrix can be decompsed into the sum of three (types) of highly symmetric matrices.  If $I_N$ is the identity matrix, $L$ is the matrix $$L=\begin{pmatrix}0&&\dots&0\\1&0&\dots&\\\vdots&1&\ddots&\vdots\\1&1&\dots&0 \end{pmatrix}$$ or the lower triangular matrix with $0$'s on the main diagonal, and $1$'s everywhere below it, and $M$ is the Toeplitz, Hermitian matrix where $D_i$, the $i$'th band above (or below) the main diagonal, is $D_i=\frac{1}{\gamma_N^i-1}$, then your matrix is just $M+\left(\frac{N+1}{2}\right)I_N-L$.  This decomposition likely won't be useful in calculating eigenvalues, but may help visualize the symmetry better.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! But I believe that γ3/(1-γ3) would not be equal to γ3-1. So is there possibly another way to look at this?

Comment: Fixed.  There's still a relationship between the diagonals above and below the main diagonal.

Comment: Thats a very good and elaborate answer :D I will take a look at the Toeplitz matrices  I think this could be the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I have sadly still not been able to solve anything, I took a look at the Toeplitz matrices but do not believe those are relevent, as they dont have anything to do with what we are doing in analysis at the moment. I forgot to mention that in the first part of the question we were asked to prove that $(F(x))_k:= \frac{1}{N^{0.5}}\sum_{j=1}^N x_je^{\frac{2pi(j-1)(k-1)}{N}}$ is norm preserving with the euclidean norm. Is this potentially helpful?